# Reputation Graph, dates bug (month level)

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

The dates labels on the X axis on the Reputation Graph are not accurate. The graph below shows FEB (2015 I assume) but I know that this peak was in december of 2014 during the Winterbash.

[image]

[Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573335/rnrneverdies?tab=topactivity)

Answer (score 7):

If you read the label as the last month of the three-month period it encompasses, it's correct: *Feb* here refers to the December to February period.  This becomes clear when you notice that the graph ends with the label *Nov*, for the current month.

Granted, the graph would make more sense if the middle month of the three-month period (in this case, January), were used for the label. It would also help if the labels weren't aligned in such a way that the *Feb* label is left-adjusted and the *Nov* label is right-adjusted. But if you know how to interpret it, it makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

While you're correct that it's wrong, this specific graph was never meant to be accurate. It's just a rough overview of your reputation over time.

If you want accuracy, visit your [Network Profile reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3035018/rnrneverdies?tab=reputation):

> [image]

As you see, this one correctly shows the peak you mentioned.